# Speeding up INSERT Query of a Pandas Dataframe into MySQL Database

Tags: python, mysql, pandas, google-cloud-platform

I am using simple `to_sql` pandas method to save dataframe into MySQL database:

```
engine = create_engine('mysql+mysqlconnector://xxxx:xxxxx@localhost:3306/db_qa')

df.to_sql('my_table', con=engine, if_exists='replace', index=False, chunksize=120, method='multi')
```

However, this way is not very fast. For a small dataframe 10000 rows and 42 columns it takes around 3 minutes to save. It should be way faster than that.

I am running mysql database on GCP (SQL instance) and also running a cloud sql proxy on a sperate VM to allow connection to the SQL instance in the cloud from.

I am trying to identify what can be bottlenecking the INSERT query. I already tried removing all `None` values from the dataframe but it did not speed up the query at all. I also experimented with chunksizes and found out that for my case 120 was the fastest. Bigger chunksizes were much slower.

I was also checking the usage of SQL instance on GCP but I could not find that anything was at the peak usage or running out of resources at all.
Are there any other ways to speed this up using python scripts or something else?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I´m currently in the same situation. Trying to insert 200k rows with 150+ columns.

Comment: @Daviid instead of using insert statement I changed the query to use `LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE` and I just provide the path to csv file that I created from my dataframe. It is much faster and actually after I fixed some VPN settings it is quite fast (even with VPN it was faster than bulk insert). One more thing I did was to filter out some rows that had too much text I think this slowed the insert query in some way. If you have 150 columns maybe you can consider splitting them into different tables as well.

Answer (score -1):

Try adding `fast\_executemany=True` parameter when using the `to\_sql` method, you can set the method parameter to multi and add the fast_executemany=True argument to the create_engine function. This is mentioned on the [documentation](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/dialects/mssql.html#fast-executemany-mode).

Also, use larger `chunksize` since it is used on batch insertion.

```
engine = create_engine('mysql+mysqlconnector://xxxx:xxxxx@localhost:3306/db_qa?fast_executemany=true')

chunksize = 1000  # Adjust the chunk size based on your data
df.to_sql('my_table', con=engine, if_exists='replace', index=False, chunksize=chunksize)
```

Comment: `fast_executemany` does not work with mysql, right?